# How to monitor the status of links?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, health-monitoring

We have over 10,000 links to websites added by clients. Can anyone recommend an approach to monitor the status of these links so I can keep track of if they are online. Would I be better off running a daily script? Or is there another way to do this?

I would be looking for a solution that would alert me when any of these links were down, and ideally update the database if the site we were linking out to was down.

We are using classic ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a daily (or even hourly) script that does an http head request on each site, and flags them if the return is not 200 OK would be the best way to do it. You could even have it be a background process on the server that fires whenever that link is viewed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dedicated service like http://aremysitesup.com/, which monitors web sites and notifies about downtime via email/sms and other media. Check their site for more info.